# Tips for golfing in Emotinomicon

Tags: code-golf, tips

What general tips do you have for golfing in [Emotinomicon](//conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to Emotinomicon (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer).

Please post one tip per answer.

Comment: Please help popularise Emotinomicon, if you can. As it stands right now, only 2 people use it AFAIK (me and Conor O'Brien).

Comment: While this is an interesting idea, there isn't precisely much room for golfing in this language, except for perhaps changing program flow. Other than that, a lot of the tips that would apply here would apply to other languages with similar code layouts.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I know, but I have alerady posted 4 answers, and might post more.

Comment: While that's true, half of them are interpreter bugs that I might fix in the future.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien That's why I've said "right now". Also, there are currently 2 of them.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @daHugLenny I don't know, maybe it was a Community Autodownvote, or someone just not liking the simplicity of this post, or even someone who wants to just cost me rep (those guys get their votes removed).

Answer (score 2):

Should be answers to respective challenges (if they exist). Note that some of these code samples might alerady be answers somewhere else.

If you just want to print `undefined`, use this 4-byte, 1-char program.

Infinite loop (6 bytes, 2 chars).

```
ℹ⏩
```

Cat (owned by Conor O'Brien) (15 bytes, 5 chars).

```
⏫⏪⏬⏫⏩
```

This program should output the 8 phases of the moon, but it doesn't seem to work (61 bytes, 16 chars).

```
⏪⏬⏩
```

Hypothenuse (27 bytes, 7 chars).

```
➕
```

Comment: It's because the string implementation grabs surrogates as well. I'll fix this sometime today, probably.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a truthy value (or even just a value), without using it, use `ℹ`. It's 3 bytes, while the others are 4 bytes.

Comment: I used this for the infinite loop challenge.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output 2 chars or less, do not use `⏪⏬⏩`, use the number of `⏬`s needed.

Answer (score 1):

## Make use of built-ins.

Some cases are:

- `⁉️❕` -> `❔`
- The numbers `0`-`10`, `100` and `i` are `ℹ`, respectively.
- Multiplication with `2`-`4` is done with `☺️`, respectively.
- Division with `2`-`4` is done with , respectively.
- Exponentiation with `2`-`4` is done with , respectively.
- Rooting:

  - n-Rooting with `n` being `2`-`4` is done with , respectively.
  - For other `n`, use `n➗`. `n` is not a literal `n`, but the power of rooting.

Answer (score 1):

## Infinite Looping

If you want to loop a program infinitely, from index `n`, you can use `n` to jump behind the `n`th character. For example, this 34-byte, 12-char program for `yes`:

```
⏪sey⏪⏬⏩⏩
```

Becomes this 32-byte, 11-char program:

```
sey⏪⏬⏩
```

Comment: It seems like I've got the grasp of it... if anyone is wondering, the `yes` idea originated [here](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32538157#32538157).

Answer (score 0):

Because of a bug in the interpreter, if you want to append `1` to a number (e.g. `10` -> `101`), use . As it is right now, you have to use `➕` for the *true* function of .

Comment: I believe this bug is because JavaScript `"123"+1` -> `"1231"`.